# How to get TogglerBar to respect image sizes?

Tags: dynamic

I'm using a `TogglerBar` with a set of images, but I can't figure out how to get it to respect the size of the images:

```
images = Table[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 15];

DynamicModule[{c = {}},
  Dynamic[TogglerBar[Dynamic[c], Thread[Range[Length[images]] -> 
    (ImageResize[#, 300] & /@ images)], Appearance -> "Row"]]]
```

Here the images are much smaller than 300. If I use `Show` with a fixed `ImageSize`, it does respect that, but is there a better way to get the `TogglerBar` not to resize things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option `BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` to `TogglerBar`:

```
DynamicModule[{c = {}}, Dynamic[TogglerBar[Dynamic[c], 
  Thread[Range[Length[images]] -> (ImageResize[#, 300] & /@ images)],
     Appearance -> "Row", BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you. The help page for BaseStyle was useless.